# "ffi.h: No such file or directory" while trying to install docker-compose on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, docker, raspberrypi, arm

I'm trying to install docker-compose on Ubuntu 20.04 (ARM Rasberry PI 4).
But when I follow official guide on [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/), I can't use standard route as there is no version on GitHub for Linux-aarch64, only x86.

But when I try alternative version via `pip install` I receive error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kn5p6q3/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kn5p6q3/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u7mx6nfb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/cffi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-2kn5p6q3/cffi/
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/c
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.8/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
       15 | #include <ffi.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kn5p6q3/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-2kn5p6q3/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u7mx6nfb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/cffi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ffi.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any), `ffi.h` is in `libffi-dev` package. To install that package, run

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

After installing the package, retry installation of docker-compose.

Comment: The command from Kulfy also works for Pi Os 'buster' in order to install docker-compose.